# Deploying apps using Chef and Splunk as a deployment server

Tags: chef, splunk

I got Splunk up and running on some EC2 instances using Chef. All is fine and dandy and I was able to deploy some apps manually by using Splunk as a deployment server. I deploy the application -> I write the changes in /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf to look like this:

`[serverClass:MugurelTest:app:mongodb]
restartSplunkWeb = 0
restartSplunkd = 1
stateOnClient = enabled`

I then run `/opt/splunk/bin/splunk reload deploy-server -auth admin:xxx` and the application appears on the cluster manager. The problem is that I would like to automate this step using Chef but none of the cookbooks seem to do that. What's the best way to go to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `template` resource to write out the file and then an `execute` resource (possibly via a notification) to run the command.